# How to share apps folder to another dropbox user

Tags: android, dropbox, sharing, dropbox-api

I am developing an app that can upload and download within dropbox folder
the dropbox automatically create an apps folder

my question is, how to share the folder to another dropbox user

i have tried before, it stated that the apps folder cannot be shared
or can I change the coding to create the folder not in the apps folder?

Comment: u may need to have public url to share dropbox file.. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765533/dropbox-sharing-file-url this issue for detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change 
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER; to 
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.DROPBOX;

if will create the folder that can share to other user

Comment: This is the right idea. App folder apps don't work with shared folders and app folders can't be shared, so you'll need to use Full Dropbox access if you want to interact with shared folders. However, note that the API does not currently have any calls for shared folders, so the user will need to manage them manually.