# Android: Dropbox api - getting thumbnail of DropboxLink

Tags: android, thumbnails, dropbox-api

I'm developing an Android application which uses the dropbox api.
I want my application to get links of images from friends dropbox acount and display it in a gallery.

In order to do that I get the share link of an image ([as shown in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765533/dropbox-sharing-file-url)) and send the url to other user. The other user get a links to images from friends and displays it in a gallery.

My question is: how can I get a thumbnail image from the DropboxLink object (from the share link) so I won't need to download the full image in order to display it in the gallery.
Like the way I can get thumbnail images of a photo in my dropbox:

```
DropboxInputStream dis = mApi.getThumbnailStream(path, ThumbSize.ICON_128x128, ThumbFormat.PNG);
```

Comment: There's currently no API for interacting with share links like this, so unfortunately there's no official or supported way to get thumbnails from a share link. We'll consider this a feature request though.

Comment: First thanks for the fast answer. Second, the best way is to download the whole image or there is any way to achieve the same behaviour?
And where can I submit or send a feature request?
@Greg

Comment: For a share link, the only supported programmatic/direct access for full file content is documented here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 If you really need thumbnails, and not the full image, the thumbnail call on the actual API is the only method, though you need to be authorized by the user of course. For feature requests, please feel free to use either https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact or https://forums.dropbox.com/forum.php?id=5